# Value = 'p.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

In my umbraco website I got a code like this

```
 var  p = currentNode.GetProperty("ucc") as Property;
 if (p != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value.Trim()))
 mailCC = p.Value;
```

But it always throws an error like this

```
Value = 'p.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Note:I am certain that P.Value is note Null
[image]

Comment: What *is* `p.Value`?  And what is the code of the property?  Is it possible that evaluating `p.Value` is throwing the exception?  And is the highlighted line in your screenshot the line where the exception occurs?

Comment: Yes It is.The error is at evaluating P.Value.And its from umbraco.I think Some one knows about umbraco can only figure this out.

Comment: `p.Value` is evaluated twice in the code you posted.  At which line does the exception thrown?  Umbraco is open source; *anyone* can figure it out.  Also: what value does `p.Value` have?

Comment: @DanPuzey:You can see the value of in the image itself._value is same as Value

Comment: Except that evidently it is not!  Can you post the code of `Value`?

Comment: Also, you may want to disable exception unwinding and "just my code" in your debug options, so that you can find out exactly where the exception is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking the `Trim()` method on `p.Value` when it's null is throwing the error. In your code, this is happening before `string.IsNullOrEmpty` gets to perform its check.

Modifying your expression to the following should fix it.

**Code:**

```
var p = currentNode.GetProperty("ucc") as Property;
if (p != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Value))
    mailCC = p.Value
```

**Reference:**

> [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) : Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Goran Mottram for pointing out the reason and giving the right suggestion. You should always check for null before doing any method call.